# Golang JSON-RPC Server Control at Shutdown

Tags: go, server, request, connection, json-rpc

I am writing a Shutdown Handler for a Program which uses Golang's built-in JSON-RPC Server and I have faced a difficulty. Could you help me with it?

I stop accepting incomming Connections, stop accepting incoming Requests for existing Connections (send an Error, to be true) but I have a Moment which I can not control or, at least, I do not know how to control.

The Question is:

How do I guarantee that Results of exisiting Requests of existing Connections are given to Clients of Golang's built-in JSON-RPC Server?

I want to control that Structure which calls RPC Methods, but it is not in my Code. For Example, I have an RPC Action 'User.Get'. I have a function named 'Get' which I control. How do I control the Code which starts this 'Get' function? Do I have to modify Google's RPC Server or is there any more effecient way?

Maybe, there is some Variable in RPC Server which holds the Number of active Requests being processed?

I see a `NumCalls()` and `numCalls` in the `methodType` in `https://golang.org/src/net/rpc/server.go`. The Problem is that this Field is not public... Moreover, the `.../rpc/server.go` uses `sync.Map` which does not compile. My Version of Golang is too old? :)

Seems that for now the easiest Way is to manipulate a global Counter from all the RPC Action Functions. :-) If you know a better Solution, please, tell me. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `net/rpc` godoc example it just shows how to use global defaults. Instead create your own rpc and http server instances.

```
import "net/rpc"
import "net/http"

rpcServer := rpc.NewServer()
// rpc stuff
httpServer := &http.Server{
    Handler: rpcServer,
}
// graceful shutdown stuff
```

For graceful shutdown, there's a few packages. I know of this one.

- https://github.com/tylerb/graceful